# Mac OS X 10.6.8 server migration to new hardware (not Lion)

Tags: migration

I have a aging iMac with 10.6.8 server, user accounts in OD, and user shares.  We have a newer mac mini with 10.6.8 server that I want to transfer over to.  Can you tell me the steps/document to help me accomplish this?  I see the apple doc for xfer to Lion, but not 10.6.8

Answer (score 1):

Using Migration Assistant in 10.6 you should be able to do this fairly easily.

Check out the following KB article from Apple : http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4413

Comment: Will clients have to trusted-rejoin the new server even though it has the same name?

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford the downtime, you will retain the most information and likely accomplish the fastest copy by performing a "Restore" of the current server's drive onto the MacMini server's drive (this should work just fine being that both machines are currently running the same OS version). This can be accomplished by using the [Disk Utility restore](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH5846) function.

Performing a restore (block copy) of the data from one drive to another will require you to boot from another disk (the 10.6 server DVD?) to perform the copy. However, this will retain all permissions, settings, trusted bindings, license, and other requirements from your previous install.

Note: restoring via Disk Utility may require you to choose to erase the MacMini server's startup disk for it to be able to perform a block copy (which is the fastest restore option).

To restore the iMac drive onto the MacMini:

1. [Boot the iMac up from the Mac OS X Server DVD](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533).
2. Boot the MacMini up into [FireWire Target Disk Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1661), and connect it to the iMac via FireWire
3. Open the "Disk Utility" program from the "Utilities" menu
4. Select your iMac's internal drive, and then click the "Restore" tab
5. Confirm that your iMac boot drive ("Server HD"?) is specified as the source
6. Confirm that your MacMini boot drive is specified as the target (drag it from the source list on the left into the "Target" field)
7. Verify that the "Erase destination" check box is enabled, and click "Restore"

This process should replicate the exact configuration that your iMac server used onto the MacMini. You will want to make sure not to connect both devices to the network at the same time if you were using a static IP address (likely with OD) on the old server.

If this is not feasible, using the Mac OS X Server migration assistant that is available during the initial Setup Assistant phase would be recommended.

If you cannot afford to have the current server shut down, it is possible to replicate all of the data that you want to transfer by hand (while booted), but it is a much more involved process.